# Javascript loop to replace text in string

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a string into a variable called `sDeleteSelected`. I have no control over what this function returns but I can mess around with what the function returns with a bit of JavaScript afterwards. The function returns this string:

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 >
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <A CLASS=ButtonItem HREF="/CRM/CustomPages/EMList/EMList.asp?SID=129805899252150&Key0=4&Key4=1&F=EMList/EMList.asp&J=EMList/EMList.asp&EMTarget=D">
        <IMG SRC="/CRM/Themes/img/color/Buttons/Delete.gif" BORDER=0 ALIGN=MIDDLE>
      </A>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD NOWRAP="TRUE" >
      <A CLASS=ButtonItem HREF="/CRM/CustomPages/EMList/EMList.asp?SID=129805899252150&Key0=4&Key4=1&F=EMList/EMList.asp&J=EMList/EMList.asp&EMTarget=D">Delete selected</A>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I want to inject two ID attributes into the HTML so that where the `CLASS=ButtonItem` attribute is shown, it should read `CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete`.

```
sDeleteSelected = sDeleteSelected.replace(/CLASS=ButtonItem/g, "CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete");
```

However, if I use a javascript global replace on it, it gives two elements in that string the same ID. What I could do with is a replace that replaces the first `CLASS=ButtonItem` with `CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete1` and the second with `CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sDeleteSelected = sDeleteSelected.replace("CLASS=ButtonItem", "CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete");
```

only replaces the first occurrence. You can make once more replace on the same string to make the second change.

Comment: I actually used this method in the end, but probably not in the way it was expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery it would be as simple as something like:

```
$('ButtonItem').each(function(i, v){
  $(v).attr('id', 'btnDelete' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
Using mystring =

step 1. HIDE your first instance

```
      mystr = substr(mystr,0,pos("CLASS=ButtonItem",mystr).concat("XXX",substr(mystr,pos("CLASS=ButtonItem",mystr) + 16);
```

step 2 add the ID to the sencond instance

```
     substr(mystr,0,pos("CLASS=ButtonItem")+16).concat(" ID=btnDelete2 ",substr(mystr,pos("CLASS=ButtonItem") + 16);
```

step put the first instance back with its ID

```
    substr(mystr,0,pos("XXX")).concat("CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete1 ",substr(mystr,pos("XXX") + 3)
```

Comment: Should that be indexOf instead of pos? Also, some missing brackets but this is the approach I will take.

Comment: Yes of course you are right - I was getting my languages mixed up. Let's say I was using pseudo code (to avoid my embarassment). The approach is a bit clunky but I'm glad it helped

Comment: @sheilak, could you accept one of the answers please.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I went about this a number of ways and without a lot of convoluted code, I settled on this:

```
var sButtonURL = CRM.URL("EMList/EMList.asp");
var sAssignSelected = CRM.Button("AssignSelected","MergeContinue.gif","javascript:updateURL();");
var sDeleteSelected = CRM.Button("DeleteSelected","Delete.gif", "javascript:updateURL();");
var sAssignTarget = sAssignSelected.replace(/CLASS=ButtonItem/,"XXX=XXX ID=btnAssign1");


sAssignTarget = sAssignTarget.replace(/CLASS=ButtonItem/,"CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnAssign2");
sAssignTarget = sAssignTarget.replace(/XXX=XXX/,"CLASS=ButtonItem");
var sDeleteTarget = sDeleteSelected.replace(/CLASS=ButtonItem/,"XXX=XXX ID=btnDelete1");
sDeleteTarget = sDeleteTarget.replace(/CLASS=ButtonItem/,"CLASS=ButtonItem ID=btnDelete2");
sDeleteTarget = sDeleteTarget.replace(/XXX=XXX/,"CLASS=ButtonItem");
```

What this does is to firstly call a function called CRM.URL which returns a properly formatted URL for me using the parameter as a destination which I would normally pass to the button function. However, I put a call to a Javascript function in the button function call so the button function call generates the HTML in the question I posted.

Then I can start messing with the HTML. I know that I'm loking for CLASS=ButtonItem so I alter the first one and replace it with a token XXX=XXX and I also add in the ID for the first button. The next line I can then replace the second CLASS=ButtonItem with the second button ID. Finally I alter the XXX=XXX token back to CLASS=ButtonItem.

Crude, but it works.